# Querying relation with condition in Laravel5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-5

I have two tables,one is client and second one client_contacts. I want list all contacts with one primary contact,which can be identify by checking is_primary field in client_contacts page.I also want response in object form.
My controller,

```
Client::with(array('contacts'))
                        ->findOrFail($id);
```

My client model

```
public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ClientContact');
}
```

In my client contacts model

```
 public function clients() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Client');
}
```

It returns all contacts for each clients,how can I put condition here and return result as object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may declare two extra relationship methods in your `Client` model, for example:

```
use ...Model;

class Client extends Model {
   // Will return a collection of ClientContact object or null (many-to-many)
   public function nonPrimaryContacts()
   {
       // Assumed is_primary is a boolean field, use whereNull('is_primary') if null
       return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ClientContact')->where('is_primary', false);
   }
   // Will return a single ClientContact object or null (one-to-many)
   public function primaryContact()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Model\ClientContact')->where('is_primary', true);
   }
}
```

Then you may use something like this:

```
Client::with(['primaryContact', 'nonPrimaryContacts'])->findOrFail($id);
```

For all contacts, you may use your `contacts` method in `Client` model.